# Force events from javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm trying force an event from javascript.

I have a "select" element in the html and i'm forcing the value of this from javascript but this does not trigger the "change" event. How can I force the event?

HTML:

```
<th><select id="filtro_select_periodo"></select></th>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    let fecha = new Date();

    cargarSelectPeriodo();

    filtro_select_periodo.value = fecha.getMonth();
};

filtro_select_periodo.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    let fecha = new Date();

    fecha = new Date(fecha.getFullYear(), e.value, fecha.getDate())

    let periodo = getFechaDesdeHasta(fecha);

    filtro_periodo_desde.value = periodo.desde;
    filtro_periodo_hasta.value = periodo.hasta;

    actulizarListado();
});
```

Comment: Events occur when the user will himself change the value of select.

Comment: @Nof, So you want to select a value in combo box then trigger the change event on it using JS

Comment: This is the correct behavior. The `change` event is only triggered by a user's interaction. Instead of trying to trigger the event, just invoke the code that the event should invoke.

Comment: @GaneshPatel You can't trigger the `change` event.

Comment: @Scott Marcus I am just trying to clear what opposite want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events don't apply to changes caused by JavaScript, only for user actions. Otherwise every JS check, formatter, etc. would cause an infinite loop when changing the user input and thus triggering itself again.

You should move the code from
`filtro_select_periodo.addEventListener("change", (e) => { [code] }`
to a function and call it after changing the value.

Comment: Thanks, I opted for this solution, but I thought you could force the event.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger JQuery events with JQuery's .trigger('eventname') method. Like

```
$(filtro_select_periodo).change(function (e) => { }); // add event listener
```

```
$(filtro_select_periodo).change(); // trigger the event in your window.onload function
```

See: https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for how to force the event with native javascript